# Switching characteristics in terms of TTL flip flops

Tags: switching, ttl

I am a complete novice when it comes to electrical things. Fine at digital logic, haven't done electricity since high school.

I'm looking at flip flops and I've run into something called switching characteristics:

[image: The switching characters]
[image: Timing as well]

Can I safely assume what it means is if I am running this flip flop at 200MHz it just means it would take 200MHz to switch over, or does it mean that the minimum speed of this flip flop is 200MHz at 1.2V?

I don't intend to run this thing at 200MHz, but a lot of these flip flops come with MHz ratings and I want to be sure there isn't a minimum speed I need to hit.

Also sorry for asking this basic question, but I'm so new to electronics that I can't effectively google my answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the 200MHz is in the minimum maximum frequency. This means that that that is the worst case maximum frequency you can expect it to operate at and it might do better. The flip flop will operate down to DC (nearly). This documentation is somewhat confusing in introducing a double negative.

The frequency of operation is usually limited by the external timing paths between Q and D of the flip flops. A google search for flipflop setup time is a good place to start.

Comment: Thank you for telling me what to google. Problems are much easier to tackle once you have a place to start.

Answer (score 1):

The MHz ratings tell the maximum clock speed that the device can be operated, so slower operation is guaranteed.

The Tpd is the propagation delay, i.e. when a clock loads data into the device, it is seen on output at a time of Tpd later (so from CLK input to Q output).

The Tw is the minimum width of the clock pulse that is reliably detected by the CLK input without problems.

The Tsu is the minimum time that the data input must be stable *before* the active clock edge on CLK input, for the operation to work as intended.

The Th is the minimum time that the data input must be stabe *after* the active clock edge on CLK input, for the operation to work as intended.

Comment: I really appreciate your taking the time to tell me what the acronyms mean. It is a huge help!